# Using Timestamp to display the date of post isn't working

Tags: php, timestamp

Had a look around but couldn't find anything useful. Basically I'm creating a blog and I'm using the TIMESTAMP type to get the date of data entry. However with the code below, the date is being set to todays date and changes everyday to display todays date.

```
<?php 
$timestamp = date_create($postData[$post]["date"]);
$newDate = date_format($timestamp, 'd'); echo$newDate; 
?>

<?php 
$timestamp = date_create($postData[$post]["date"]);
$newDate = date_format($timestamp, 'M'); echo$newDate 
?>
```

I want to display the time from the database. I am new to PHP so I am aware it could be a simple mistake.

Comment: Don't include tags in question title.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
date_create(null); //produces current date
?>
```

This is seems to be returning null:

```
($postData[$post]["date"])
```

That's why its giving the current date.